# Find upper boundary of an absolute value of a integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I can't prove that 
$\mid \int_0^{\pi}\frac{Rcosx}{R^2cos^2x+1}dx\mid \leq \int_0^\pi\frac{R}{R^2-1}dx$.

Could you help me with a hint?

Comment: Did you at least evaluate either integral? If so, you should edit your question to show what you found.

Comment: I am not sure if you have a typo in your question.  As far as I can tell, the right hand side integral is equal to $\pi\frac{R}{R^2-1}$ which is less than zero if $R<-1$ or $0<R<1$.  In those cases, you can't prove the result because the result is false.    If $R>1$, I suggest you graph $\cos(x)/(R^2 \cos^2 x +1)$ for $R=2$ or $R=3$.  I think that will give you a hint about the value of the left hand side.

Comment: I was not supposed to evaluate integrals. Only to show inequality,

Comment: Since, as pointed out by @irchans the right side can be negative, making the inequality false, I suspect the expression is supposed to be $\dfrac{R}{R^2+1}$ rather than $\dfrac{R}{R^2-1}$. In that case the inequality is true because the integral on the left is identically zero.

Comment: I was thinking the same, it doesn't work for $R>1$ too.

Answer (score 1):

You asked for a hint, so here it is:

Make the substitution $u=x-\frac{\pi}{2}$ and then use the fact that $\sin(u)$ is an odd function.

Comment: Note that I hesitated to answer your question because (1) you gave no evidence that you had tried to solve it yourself and (2) your history shows that when other made serious attempts to answer your past questions, you neither selected nor upvoted their answers. I suspect this is why no one had responded to your question hours after you asked it.

Comment: I  am not supposed to solve the integrals, but to use inequalities instead. And, that is what I can't do. So, substitution you've suggested won't work.Thank you very much!　I will do my best to up vote  answers.